# Replace array data special character getting from JSON by Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my application i need to get some data from JSON and convert it to an array for further use.

And I have my codes to get and convert the data:

```
var Persons = data.Persons;
var PersonsArr = [];

for (var i=0; i < Persons.length; i++){
    PersonsArr.push(Persons[i].word);
    }
```

This is quite simple, i just call the api and use a single for loop to get everything. The out come is like

```
PersonsArr=["peter","mary","tom"];
```

Then i append it to an element but it has "," to split each of the data and i'd like to remove it.

So i tried to use .replace()

```
for (var i=0; i < Persons.length; i++){
    PersonsArr.push(Persons[i].word.replace(",", " "));
                }
```

But it's not working as my exceptation, am i using the wrong apporch?

Comment: There are no commas. This is just JavaScript printing the array in a form you can read. But there are no commas internally in the array, so you are doing just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then i append it to an element but it has ","

When an array is appended as `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` to an `html` element the array is converted to a string, for example, compare results of `PersonsArr.toString()` .

---

Use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> **Syntax**
>  `str = arr.join([separator = ','])`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **separator**
>  Optional. Specifies a string to separate each element of the array. The separator is converted to a string if
>   necessary. If omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma.
>   If separator is an empty string, all elements are joined without any
>   characters in between them.

with `" "` space character as parameter when appending `PersonArr` to element as `html`

```
PersonArr.join(" ")
```

---

```js
var PersonsArr = ["peter", "mary", "tom"];
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var text = document.createElement("text");
text.textContent = PersonsArr.join(" ");
div.appendChild(text);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know about the rest of it, but this could cause the error (the g stands for a global change throughout the string)

```
.replace(",", " "))
```

should be

```
.replace(/,/g, " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're trying to remove ',' from `PersonsArr=["peter","mary","tom"];` you can't. Because that's an array and thats how it stores the value. And its not added by the data you get from the api. So if you try to access `personArr[0]` it'll return `peter` and there'll be no ','.
 If this is not what you're trying to do please let me know.

Comment: should i use .slice()

Comment: There is no ',' there actually. But still if you don't want to see it then don't put it inside an array. `var personArr = "";                                     for (var i=0; i < Persons.length; i++){
    PersonsArr+=Persons[i].word;
    } In this case there'll be no ',' or' " '